# React Native: Can't fix FlatList keys warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to render a FlatList from json fetched from an api, but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`.
```

Relevant code:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.tunes}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    <Item
      key={item.id}
      title={item.title}
      composer={item.composer}
      year={item.year}
    />
  }}
/>
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this, but after a few days of trying different things I haven't found it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you certain that the item.id is different for each item? And be sure that there is no duplicate item in the data.

Comment: Maybe this is where i'm confused. There is no item.id in the json, but I thought maybe React would provide it in this case. Do I have to map the json adding an id to each item before giving the data to FlatList?

Comment: you need to create the key yourself. you can do something like `item.name + index` or something can be unique for each item and won't change

Comment: Have you tried `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}` ?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that fixed the error!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you need to change `key` to `id` as you write `item.id` in `keyExtractor` and be sure you have id and it's different for each component:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.tunes}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    <Item
      id={item.id} //instead of key
      title={item.title}
      composer={item.composer}
      year={item.year}
    />
  }}
/>
```

Or if you don't have unique key use `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}`

Comment: Thank you for item.id in keyExtractor