# can't dislplay flatlist from array of values without keys/id in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building a photo-feed application in react-native.
for testing whether I am displaying images form array, I am using demo-array, as `photo_feed: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],`

I am able to display single `<View>` for one image, but for array of images using `flatList`, I am getting blank screen.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947921/react-native-cant-fix-flatlis) answer from SO, but my data doesn't has id for each element,

code of single-image-view is

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text> feed </Text>
        </View>

        {/* Signle Image Component. */}
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>Time ago</Text>
            <Text>@username</Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Image
              source={{
                // uri:
                //   "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x" +
                //   Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 500)

                uri: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/50x70/"
              }}
              style={styles.profilephoto}
            />
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text>Caption of post</Text>
            <Text>View all Comments</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
```

single image is displayed properly, but how can I display images for all elements in array?

[GitHub repo link of project.](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/exchange-o-gram/commits/master)

code of `feed.js` is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, FlatList } from "react-native";

class feed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      photo_feed: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], // this is data of our app
      refresh: false
    };
  }

  loadNew = () => {
    console.log("LoadNew() is called");
    this.setState({
      refresh: true
    });
    this.setState({
      photo_feed: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      refresh: false // after loading new photos [5,6,7,8,9] stop refreshing feed
    });
  };

  render() {
    let i = 0;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text> feed </Text>
        </View>

        <FlatList
          refreshing={this.state.refresh}
          onRefresh={this.loadNew}
          data={this.state.photo_feed}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => "" + index}
          style={styles.flatlist}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            console.log("index is " + index);
            // console.log("item is " + item);
            // return one element for each item.

            <View key={index}>
              <View>
                <Text>Time ago</Text>
                <Text>@username</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Image
                  source={{
                    // uri:
                    //   "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x" +
                    //   Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 500)

                    uri: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x800/"
                  }}
                  style={styles.profilephoto}
                />
              </View>

              <View>
                <Text>Caption of post</Text>
                <Text>View all Comments</Text>
              </View>
            </View>;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  header: {
    height: 70,
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "lightgrey",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  profilephoto: {
    resizeMode: "cover",
    width: "100%",
    height: 250
  },
  flatlist: {
    flex: 1
    // backgroundColor: "#0ee"
  }
});
export default feed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the item which has to be rendered. The best practice will be to make a new function and return the item.

```
 _renderItem = (item, index) => {
    console.log(item, index);
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <View>
          <Text>Time ago</Text>
          <Text>@username</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Image
            source={{
              // uri:
              //   "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x" +
              //   Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 500)

              uri: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x800/"
            }}
            style={styles.profilephoto}
          />
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>Caption of post</Text>
          <Text>View all Comments</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    let i = 0;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text> feed </Text>
        </View>        

        <FlatList
          refreshing={this.state.refresh}
          onRefresh={this.loadNew}
          data={this.state.photo_feed}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => "" + index}
          style={styles.flatlist}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. but now the same image is displayed for all items as this https://imgur.com/ocWGDME. extra ques 1) why random images are now shown instead of same img? 2) why your solution worked, after separating function from `Flatlist`?

Comment: 1. You have to make the uri of the image dynamic, for this you can update photo_feed as photo_feed =  [{uri: 'url of first image', key: '5', value: '5'}, {uri: ''uri of second image, key: '6', value: '6'}]. Finally
 <Image
            source={{
              uri: item.uri
            }}
</Image> 

2. It isn't compulsory to separate the function but it is always a good practice. The thing is you need to return the element or the item which has to be rendered. Go through this for reference https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your array and pass image uri to `Image` tag

```
 <Image
          source={{
            // uri:
            //   "https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x" +
            //   Math.floor(Math.random() * 800 + 500)

            uri: {e.g : this.image.uri}
          }}
```